# How to get attribute of child anchor with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am learning `HtmlAgilitiPack` and I want ask you, how to get value(**I want get this value**):

From HTML page:

```
<div id="js_citySelectContainer" class="select_container city_select shorten_text replaced"> 
<span class="dropDownButton ownCity coords">
<a>i want get this value</a>
</span>
</div>
```

C# code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
Console.writeln(echo i want get this value);
```

I tried:

```
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("span").Where(s => s.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "dropDownButton ownCity coords").First().InnerText;
```

But it doesnt work, can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Might i recommend CsQuery instead then you can use normal css queries im not 100% but i think you could write some thing like `cq("span.dropDownButton.ownCity.coords")`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the XPATH syntax:

```
var span = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='dropDownButton ownCity coords']");
var anchorText = span.ChildNodes["a"].InnerText;
```

You can also use LINQ:

```
var anchorTexts = 
    from span in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("span")
    where span.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "dropDownButton ownCity coords" 
    from anchor in span.Descendants("a") 
    select anchor.InnerText;
string anchorText = anchorTexts.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you, but i getting a error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: @thounudi: i have tested both approaches with your sample HTML. Are you sure that you have used the code above(i've edited it).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think that you can get that exception in anchor.InnerText if span doesn't have anchor childs

Comment: @faby: yes you can exceptions, but OP's sample HTML contains the anchor. Of course it can throw exceptions if the document is different. It's not fail-safe.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I'm sorry, I'm started old code ! :-( Now everything is OK , thank you for the explanation and advice

Comment: FYI, you can use  `span.GetAttributeValue("class","")` to prevent `NullReferenceException`  when the span doesn't have class.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to get the `span` text, you need the `a` text

try this

```
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("span")
.Where(s => s.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "dropDownButton ownCity coords")
.First().Descendants("a").First().InnerText;
```